# "This" vs "that" in past tense narrative

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

Here are some examples (first person past tense):

> "Well, goodby then." After saying **this/that**, he picked up his hat and ran out door.
>
> I let his words sink in my head. *To fight alone*. Was **this/that** true
>   even though we had each other?

Does the meaning change if I pick the former or the later? Which one is more common in fiction?

Comment: This is essentially a [rephrase request](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic), which is off-topic here. Closing, but feel free to edit this into something more substantial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any huge detriment story-wise (or even grammar-wise), but I would suggest "this" for the first and "that" for the second. However, I wouldn't phrase the first passage that way since it's a bit stilted and odd to read. You could say…

> "Well, goodbye then," he said as he picked up his hat and ran out the door.

…or you could just say…

> "Well, goodbye then." He picked up his hat and ran out the door.

I'd have to see the context, but it should help the flow.